# What kind of string does snippet.defaultLanguage take?

Tags: youtube, google-api, google-api-nodejs-client

When I upload a video to my youtube channel, I'd like to be able to specify the defaultLanguage. However, the [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource) don't seem to be specify what kind of string I should put.

> string This property is confidential to trusted testers.
>
> The language of the text in the video resource's snippet.title and
>   snippet.description properties.

What kind of string does snippet.defaultLanguage take?

```
resource: {
  snippet: {
    defaultLanguage: "English" //<-- correct ?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"en"` is the correct string to put to set the default language.